# The method copyWith can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null

Tags: flutter

```
body: Container(
        ...
        child: Text(
          'This is Container Widget',
          style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline4
            .copyWith(color:Colors.white)
        ),
      ),
```

The method copyWith can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null 
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: in which case `Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4` is null?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `?` because the `headline4` is Nullable type `final TextStyle? headline4;`
So when you are invoking the nullable type method without `?` this error occurs

```
body: Container(
        ...
        child: Text(
          'This is Container Widget',
          style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline4?.copyWith(color:Colors.white)
        ),
      ),
```